# JavaScript: Trying to subtract two variables returns NaN for me

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple calorie calculator and for some odd reason, my math for totalCalories (which is calories, an integer, minus calorieDeduction, an integer) keeps returning NaN. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I've tested console.log outputs on both my calories entered and on calorieDeduction and they both return as integers. I don't understand why subtracting one from the other returns NaN, unless I need to maybe define totalCalories as an integer by hand. I'm a newbie so I'm not necessarily sure the best method to do that. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
var maxCaloriesCodes = ['FMW', 'FLW', 'MMW', 'MLW'];
var maxCaloriesAllowed = [2000, 1500, 2500, 2000];
var exerciseCodes = ['FL', 'FM', 'FV', 'ML', 'MM', 'MV'];
var exerciseCalories = [240, 370, 580, 300, 460, 730];

function performAssessment(){

var genderElem = document.getElementById('gender_id');
var genderValue = genderElem.options[genderElem.selectedIndex].value;
var genderText = genderElem.options[genderElem.selectedIndex].text;

var goalElem = document.getElementById('goal_id');
var goalValue = goalElem.options[goalElem.selectedIndex].value;
var goalText = goalElem.options[goalElem.selectedIndex].text;

var exerciseElem = document.getElementById('exercise_id');
var exerciseValue = exerciseElem.options[exerciseElem.selectedIndex].value;
var exerciseText = exerciseElem.options[exerciseElem.selectedIndex].text;

var caloriesCode = genderValue + goalValue;
var caloriesAllowed;
var completeExerciseCodes = genderValue + exerciseValue;
var calorieDeduction;
var totalCalories;

// Loop through the array and locate the code to get the maximum calories
for (var codeCount = 0; codeCount < maxCaloriesCodes.length; codeCount++) {
    // Determine if the current code is the array
    if (maxCaloriesCodes[codeCount] == caloriesCode) {
        caloriesAllowed = maxCaloriesAllowed[codeCount];
    }
}

totalCalories = (calories - calorieDeduction);

// Loop through my exercise arrays and locate codes for calorie deductions
for (var codeCount = 0; codeCount < exerciseCodes.length; codeCount++){
    // Determine if the current code is in the array
    if (exerciseCodes[codeCount] == completeExerciseCodes) {
        calorieDeduction = exerciseCalories[codeCount];
    }
}

console.log(totalCalories)
}
```

Comment: Where is `calorieDeduction` initialized? If it's not explicitly set to *something* its value will be `undefined`, and subtraction will give you `NaN`.

Comment: You are saying `totalCalories = (calories - calorieDeduction)`; before you have defined what `calorieDeduction` is

Comment: `calorieDeduction` isn't set to anything, so it's `undefined`.

Comment: It was initialized in my for loop but I define totalCalories before the loop. I moved the line and that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Many comments which should/could be answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for loops, if-clauses or function calls, code is executed line by line from top to bottom. In the line where you execute `totalCalories = (calories - calorieDeduction)`, neither `calories` nor `calorieDeduction` has a value. Or actually their value is `undefined`, which gives you NaN.